# Cloudant delete / restore LARGE number of records in cloudant / couchdb

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, bulkupdate

I have come across threads about restoring deleted documents, from cloudant or couchdb.

However we have a cloudant database with more than 50 million records. And we have a requirement to cleanup this database, and restore a document based on a flag stored in an external SQL db. We are exploring if we can mark all documents as deleted and then restore only the required ones ?

Would this be feasible at such a scale ? 50 million users ? Any inputs about what strategy can be used are highly appreciated.

Comment: After you delete a document, its content is no longer accessible in the changes feed, only the revisions. So you would have to explicitly request the last _rev of the deleted document, in order to check the external flag. This is why I would not delete all documents first.